# Passing data between AWS lambda from the step functions using api gateway in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have a special use case. I have to call the step function from api gateway using a POST call which is APIGatewayProxyEvent with two tasks, finally I have to aggregate the result and return as a single response.

Task 1 takes the input as APIGatewayProxyEvent as input and call a lambda function L1 and return a result in form of APIGatewayProxyResult

Task 2 takes the input as APIGatewayProxyEvent as input and call a lambda function L2 and return a result in form of APIGatewayProxyResult

But the problem is Task 2 L2 is not working since it is expecting APIGatewayProxyEvent but in turn it gets APIGatewayProxyResult

I have used outputPath resultPath inputPath for manipulating the data but still there is no possible outcome and I am getting a blank response.

I tried all possible outcomes need a help here.

Comment: Do Task 1 and Task 2 both take the same input, the original APIGatewayProxyEvent?

Comment: Task 1 input will be APIGatewayProxyEvent which will return APIGatewayProxyResponse. Task 2 should use this APIGatewayProxyResponse and process further and aggregate the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.